# What is the name of this drawing style of images?

Tags: drawing, style-identification, illustration

Please ignore the added filters:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post what the image looked like without the filters?

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't say this is really a specific art type but "Naïve figurative marker drawing" or "cartoon style marker art" come to mind.